# MongoDb index reference to original table

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I testing how indexes work in MongoDB and don't understand one moment.

I have a test collection with data (10000 rows):
[image: test collection]

Also I creating new index:

```
collection.createIndex({ SomeValue1: 1, SomeValue2: -1 })
```

And I don't understand how the index maps its own entries to the original table. 
I thought that it uses the '_id' column but these two queries said me that this isn't true:

---

#1:

```
collection
.find()
.sort({ SomeValue1: 1, SomeValue2: -1 })
.projection({ SomeValue1: 1, SomeValue2: 1 })
.explain("allPlansExecution")
```

#2:

```
collection
.find()
.sort({ SomeValue1: 1, SomeValue2: -1 })
.projection({ SomeValue1: 1, SomeValue2: 1, _id: 0 })
.explain("allPlansExecution")
```

---

At #1 query execution plan says:

```
"totalKeysExamined": 10000,
"totalDocsExamined": 10000,
```

At #2:

```
"totalKeysExamined": 10000,
"totalDocsExamined": 0,
```

I was expecting that both variants don't use the original table.
Found this information on official documentation: [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#covered-queries)
But still don't understand how to index entry matches entry from the original table if it (index table) doesn't use the '_id' field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying Wired Tiger storage engine is a key-value store.  When a document is stored, WiredTiger assigns in an internal identifier as a key, with the document as the value, and stores it in a structure similar to a B-Tree.

Indexes are also trees, with the key derived values of the indexes field, and the value the internal identifier used as the document key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please give the cue where I can read more about the internal realization and infrastructure of mongo?

Comment: The WiredTiger internals used to be over at wiredtiger.com, but since MongoDB acquired them, I'm not sure where or if that is available any more.